# Need to generate QR Code in Oracle

Tags: oracle11g, qr-code, zxing, bi-publisher, java-5

I am in need of generating QR Code in oracle database and print them in PDF document generated through BI Publisher.

I have tried many places and found below post which makes use of Zxing Library to generate QR Code in Oracle DB through Zxing Library:
https://community.oracle.com/message/13360407#13360407

But the db in which i am currently working is having Java 1.5 but zxing needs 1.6/1.7

I have asked Zxing group whether they have any older version which supports 1.5:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/zxing

In the meanwhile tried looking for qrcode generator which is purely pl/sql and found below in GITHUB:
**1. as_barcode by antonscheffer**
and
**2. make_qr by svetka17**

But both the pl/sql package is missing something and giving out error.

Do you guys know any idea how i can generate qr code in pl/sql or any Java 1.5 qr code library which i can use in Oracle Database ?

Opensource will be helpful and not interested in IDAutomation as its out of my budget.

Thanks and Regards,
Salman Farish.

Answer (score 0):

A new version of BI Publisher (12.2.1.4) provides QR codes as a feature.

https://blogs.oracle.com/xmlpublisher/oracle-bi-publisher-12214-now-available
https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/bi-publisher/new-features-12214-4470018.pdf

Answer (score -1):

There is a pure Plsql package to generate QR code.

There are options to generate QR code as BMP, SVG etc.

https://oraclescribble.blogspot.com/2022/08/create-qr-code-in-oracle-database-pure.html

Comment: Please don't just post some tool or library as an answer. At least demonstrate [how it solves the problem](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605) in the answer itself.